# Are variable values refreshed in popup.js in Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, google-chrome-app

I am developing a Chrome extension trying to gather all the selected texts from one page. I used a content script to catch the selected text and pass it to popup.js and append it to an array, then display it in popup.html so each time the users click the popup can see what they've selected.

However whenever I select something, popup.html does show it, but all the texts I selected before are all gone. And the array always keeps the length of 1. Which makes me think if the popup page refreshes every time you click it.

I could not figure it out so would you help me? What I want to know is: if popup does refresh every time you click it, how should I save the variables; if it doesn't, when what is my problem.

My popup.js code is as below:

```
var totalSelection = [];
var selectionDisplay = '';

if (chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().newSelectedText !== undefined) {
    text = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().newSelectedText;
    addTextInArray(text);
    addTextToPopup();
    if (totalSelection.length > 1)
        console.log("length: " + totalSelection.length.toString() + "\n" + totalSelection.toString());
}

function addTextInArray(message) {
    totalSelection.push(message);
    selectionDisplay += "<p>" + message + "</p>";
}

function addTextToPopup() {
    document.getElementById("container2").innerHTML = selectionDisplay;
}
```

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Popup pages do refresh every time you re-open them. They're just `html` files. There's no reason for them to stay opened in background ( you have [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) for that ).

You could do one of the following:

- Use [storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), for which you will need to add an additional permission to your `manifest.json` file.
- Store your array in background script and use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to pass the data

**Note**: Watch out when gathering sensitive data from users. Google has a strict policy on this and If you plan to publish your extensions, you better make it clear to the user that you're collecting data. Also, make sure you're compliant with [single purpose policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/single_purpose).

Comment: I believe you could also use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this too, it would be easier than `chrome.storage`

Comment: Hey thank you both @ Transcendental @NoamHacker so much for the answers. I appreciate it.

Comment: A following question: If I am gonna use "chrome.storage" to store variables, I can set and get the variables from any script file with the extension (e.g. popup.js, background.js, contentScript.js) right? No matter the variable is defined by which script, as soon as it is in "chrome.storage" then it's available to any file right?

Comment: Not only you can use it anywhere, you can also set an `onChange` listener in your background page so you'll immediately know when The storage content changes.